# Automatic weights deforming my character

Tags: mesh, game-engine, objects, rigging, armature

[image]I'm having problems when I want to set the mesh as the armature parent. Once I press Ctrl+P to open the menu and select "With automatic weights" it deforms the mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your mesh
2. Delete the armature modifier it has and delete it's parent and delete all vertex groups
3. Select your armature
4. Switch to Pose mode
5. Select all bones
6. Press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and write

   Apply Pose as Rest Pose
7. Select mesh then armature then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `with automatic weighting`

Comment: THX. U AWESOME.

Comment: In Blender 2.8, the search menu has moved from `Space Bar` to `F3`.